# How change $PATH for RStudio

Tags: macos, command-line, path, r

I am trying to set my `$PATH` variable for RStudio. Somehow it just ignores the entry in my `~/.Renviron`. I added this lines:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/bin
R_MAX_VSIZE=100Gb
```

if I run `Sys.getenv("PATH")` it just shows my `PATH` without the addition I made. If I run `Sys.getenv("R_MAX_VSIZE")` it shows `100Gb`, so the `.Renviron` file is recognized.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/04/19/r-for-enterprise-understanding-r-s-startup/

One of your other rc files might be getting the priority over `~/.Renviron`. If that's what's happening, that `R_MAX_VSIZE` is still set to your desirable value could mean that it's set to `100GB` somewhere outside `~/.Renviron`.

Comment: I just found out, that, if I start interactive `R` in the terminal, it recognizes the variable. However the output of `system("echo $PATH")` is then `$PATH:/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/bin`. So, it does not replace the variable `PATH` with its actual value.